# Messaging contacts color change

Tags: sms

I got my Galaxy S3 about two weeks ago, and have been texting on it normally. Now, for some reason, when I look at my text log some of the names of my contacts are in blue, while some remain in white. It started with a few names becoming blue, and now the majority are. It's a completely random thing, but I'm just wondering why..

Comment: My girlfriend's Samsung Fascinate is experiencing the same behavior ... in her Text Messaging window, some of her contacts' name's are in blue, and some are in white. They change, for no discernable reason.

Answer (score 3):

I see a discussion in [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/585929-messaging-app-some-senders-blue-others-white.html) stating that this behavior is a *strange* bug.  It seems that few experienced this issue for whom the color changed after receiving an emergency message.  They also say that deleting such messages restores the color. If you had received any such emergency message, can you please try to delete it?

Out of curiosity and the attraction of bounty led me to search for this issue else where. I do not have an S3 or know anyone having S3 to confirm this.

Comment: to the up voter: thanks at first. Could you please add a comment if deleting the emergency message did solve the issue? This will also help other S3 users.

Comment: The upvoter needn't necessarily own an S3 to find your answer useful, both Maarx and Emma haven't been here since you posted your answer (seen in their profiles)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug concerning severe weather alerts. Simply delete the culprit message, then force-stop the messaging app. Everything should go back to normal. You may permanently disable the culprit messages from coming in by going to messaging>settings>emergency alerts and uncheck the boxes.

As confirmed on: http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-galaxy-s-iii/192562-text-messages-all-changed-blue.html